# Let $\log_{10}⁡2 = x$ and $\log_{10}⁡3 = y$. Express the $\log_{10}5$ in terms of $x$ and/or $y$.

Tags: logarithms

Let $\log_{10}⁡2 = x$ and $\log_{10}⁡3 = y$. Express the $\log_{10}5$ in terms of $x$ and/or $y$.

I am stuck on finding a way to express $5$ as a product or quotient of $x$ and $y$.

Any help, comment, or suggestions on how to solve this problem will be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: $1=log_{10} 10=log_{10} (2 × 5)$

Comment: $log_{10}5 = log_{10}(10/2)$

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is $1-x$
$$1-x$$
$$\log_{10}(10)-\log_{10}(2)$$
$$\log_{10}(\frac{10}{2})$$
$$\log_{10}(5)$$

Answer (score 0):

Reversing some of the given log's almost always worked for me:
$$\lg5=A \implies \color{red}{\log_52}+1=\frac{1}{A}$$
$$x=\lg2 \implies \log_25+1=\frac{1}{x} \implies \log_52=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}-1}=\frac{x}{1-x}$$
$$\frac{1}{A}=\color{red}{\frac{x}{1-x}}+1=\frac{1}{1-x}\implies \boxed{A=1-x}$$